# NSButton keyEquivalentModifierMask not work with .control modifier flag

Tags: swift, macos

I have a `NSButton` in my project what has to work with hotkey `ctrl+a`. For this I set

```
button.keyEquivalentModifierMask = .control
button.keyEquivalent = "a"
```

But in some strange reason hotkey works on `cmd+a` combination instead of expected `ctrl+a`.

And if I will do `button.keyEquivalentModifierMask == .command` it will return `true`.

Anyone can explain why does it work like this or maybe there is some known issue with using `NSEvent.ModifierFlags.control`?

FYI: project builded with Xcode 10.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps control+a is being used elsewhere (by the system even).
Key Event Handling in Cocoa Applications WWDC 2010 video is useful.

[WWDC 2010 Key Event Handling in Cocoa Applications · Session 145](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__hd/session_145__key_event_handling_in_cocoa_applications.mov)

Taken from https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/387544/3051702

Comment: I don't want to watch the video, what is the answer? Is it possible to use `.control` in `keyEquivalentModifierMask`?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Although whether setting it makes it to the menu is dependent on other factors. NSMenu works to prevent key collisions. Some key combinations my be set outside the application.

Comment: `-[NSButtonCell setKeyEquivalentModifierMask:` clears the control flag and adds the command flag. Please post a working code snippet.